# Stop or move the mouse

Tags: .net, winforms, gdi+

I have a graphical application in which I move a graphic object with the mouse.

In some conditions, the object stops moving. I need then to stop moving the mouse cursor too.

Is it possible? `MousePosition` property seems to be in ReadOnly.

Eg.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.X > 100)
        {
            Cursor.Position = new Point(100, Cursor.Position.Y);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT, second version, works, but the cursor is not "stable" - flickering:

```
    private void Form1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.X > 100)
        {
            Point mousePosition = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
            mousePosition.X = 100;
            Point newScreenPosition = this.PointToScreen(mousePosition);
            Cursor.Position = newScreenPosition;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can replace this code with a single call to ClipCursor, where the rectangle is `{0, 0, 100, Form.Height}` (converted from client coordinates to screen coordinates, obviously).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [ClipCursor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648383(VS.85).aspx) function via PInvoke. If the bouding rectangle is small enough, the mouse will not move.

---

EDIT

An example:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=1)]
public struct RECT {
    public int left;
    public int top;
    public int right;
    public int bottom;
};


public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ClipCursor([In()]ref RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ClipCursor([In()]IntPtr lpRect);


    private bool locked = false;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (locked) {
            ClipCursor(IntPtr.Zero );
        }
        else {
            RECT r;

            Rectangle t = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, this.ClientSize.Height);
            t = this.RectangleToScreen(t);

            r.left = t.Left;
            r.top = t.Top;
            r.bottom = t.Bottom;
            r.right = t.Right;

            ClipCursor(ref r);
        }

        locked = !locked;

    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: e.. what is the usage in .NET?

Comment: what do you mean "small enough"? and if not?

Comment: The .net declarations for c# and vb are at the bottom of this article.

Comment: @serhio here's the usage in .NET: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.ClipCursor
(it even gives you all the proper struct definitions)

Comment: ... and if not, the cursor will move inside this rectangle. If the rectangle is as big as one pixel, the cursor will freeze.

Comment: see the example. I need do not allow mouse pass over 100px left margin.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using `Cursor.Position`?

E.g.

```
Cursor.Position = new Point(100, 100);
```

You could keep setting it to a constant value (like Vulcan said).

Comment: I use OnMouseMove e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs

and seems that e.Location is not synchronized with Cursor.Position... Also I have visible cursor "feedback" when using it...

Comment: @serhio That's strange...how off-sync is it?

Comment: @serhio hmm...not sure where to go from there

Comment: I found the cause, but still not happy, because of flickering... :)